# Use mathematical induction to show that when n is an exact power of 2, the solution of the recurrence...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

So, I am trying to understand the algebraic simplifications going on in this proof and I understand the answer to the proof, but I just don't understand the algebra.

How do they get to the highlighted step?  How do they get rid of the T?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

They used the inductive hypothesis.  You are assuming that $T(2^k)=2^k\log(2^k)$, and trying to show that $T(2^{k+1})=2^{k+1}\log(2^{k+1})$.

Comment: Ah thanks!  Can't believe I didn't see that!  I am going to take a break and then will come back to it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is where they make use of the hypothesis.  You are given $T(n)=n \log n$ when $n=2^k$, so $T(2^k)=2^k \log(2^k)$  They have made that substitution.  This is usual for induction proofs.  You have a hypothesis about what happens at $k$ and show the rule applies at $k+1$.  To do that, you relate what happens at $k+1$ using your hypothesis.