# Base case is $2 \log(2) = 2$? - Proof by induction that $T(n) = n \times \log(n)$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I've found solutions explaining how the proof works, however I'm stuck on the base case, as I'm showing $2*\log (2) = 0.602$.  But the proof says it's $2$. How are they getting that?

The problem is explained [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947309/use-mathematical-induction-to-show-that-when-n-is-an-exact-power-of-2-the-solut)
and [**here**](https://ita.skanev.com/02/03/03.html).

screen shot of problem
[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2 \log 2= 2$ only if you are considering $\log$ to denote a base 2 logarithm.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't know $\lg$ could be interpreted as $\log_2$  I always thought it was base 10 unless otherwise specified.  A couple quick google searches seem to conflict each other as well.